# Dynamic 2D array: Space Issue

Tags: c++

I am using the following code to create dynamic 2D array.

```
uint32_t** arrays = new uint32_t*[1000]; 
uint32_t number = take input from console ;
arrays[0] = new uint32_t[number];
number = take input from console ;
arrays[1] = new uint32_t[number];
delete arrays[0] ;
number = take input from console ;
arrays[0] = new uint32_t[number] ;
```

I am using 64 bit Unix machine to execute above code.

In the above code the machine is taking 64 bit pointer to point 2nd dimension array and that's why the code is taking more space.

Can anyone help me, how to convert the code thus it takes 32 bit pointer ? Or another way to solve space complexity ? I don't want to use vector of vectors as it is not asked to do by my prof.

Comment: Can't afford 64 bit pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your code is already pretty much memory optimized as it is.

You allocate a 1000 64-bit pointers in your first line. That's unavoidable since that is what your machine uses. However, that only takes 8000 bytes, hardly worth the effort optimizing these days.

In the next lines, you dynamically allocate space for int32_t arrays, which only take 4 bytes per entry. So if you allocate 30 million entries, it will take 120.000.000 bytes. I think you are mistaken in thinking that this secondary array will take 30 million * 8 bytes = 240.000.000 bytes, which it doesn't. Only the pointer is 64 bit, the data itself will take up as much or as little space as it needs.

**Addendum**: I want to add that allocating a two dimensional array, as some have suggested, will actually waste more memory, since your clearly don't know how long each secondary entry will be. Your solution allocates only as much space as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have no control over the pointer size on your system.

Opt not to care or, better yet, use an actual 2D array instead of an array of pointers.

Comment: As you say using a 2d array rather than an array of pointers would decrease the memory requirements. It's the good old 'arrays and pointers are the same thing' myth cropping up again.

Comment: how to use "actual 2D array" with dynamic 2nd dimension with out pointer ? 1st dimension will be larger (30 million approx.).

Comment: `new uint32_t[1000 * (your input from console)];` and flatten/expand 2D indices when array access is required.

Comment: The original question is not about creating matrices, but real dynamic 2D arrays, and I think your solution only fits matrices. You don't know that the length of the second dim is a constant value, so you can't declare the array to be of 1000*x and be done with it

Comment: This answer is about creating a matrix instead of a dynamic 2D array so that you don't have to frak about with pointers, but get _all_ of the benefits anyway... You're right though in that I've overlooked the original array may not necessarily be rectangular. That seems like a difficult array to manage in the first place, though, and implies that a proper container might make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a crazy idea, but than again, your question is not the most standard either.

Why not use only offsets from the base address of the heap? You'll be limited to 32bit heap address space (4GB heap), but if you don't want to give up those extra 4 bytes required for a 64bit pointer, that's a limitation you'll have a hard time overcoming.

The idea is to get the base address of your heap (possible, even if not completely simple), it in a global variable - lets call it heap_base...or something like that.

Now, when you create a pointer, don't store it's whole value in the first array, only store it's its offset (the difference) from heap_base.
When you want to access an element, restore the correct pointer value with addition.

This might not work - it depends on how the OS will allocate data on the heap - but I figured it might give you a nice idea for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The other (rather more f*#@&d up way) to look at it is  use 1 64bit pointer to store 2 32 bit number. So have arrays of 64 bit numbers, and then in each element store two 32 bit numbers.

And then write separate methods for accessing these as 32 bit values using bit manipulation and other ways e.g. your get will look something like.

```
uint32_t get (int i, int j)
{
   if (j % 2 == 0) 
    {
      return array[i][j/2] % (2^32)
    }
    else
    {
      return array[i][j/2] / (2^32)
    }
};
```

Comment: sorry, above code is just an example. It may store more than 2 32 bit number in 2nd dimension according to input.